# How to join 2 dataframes based on paired values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm looking to find a function that joins a column from one df to another based on whether the two dfs have the same paired vars. For example, `Var1` `Var2` is the same as `Var2` `Var1`.

Here's a mock example:

```
Var1 <- c(1,2,6,5,5)
Var2 <- c(4,3,1,5,6)
f <- c("blue","green","red","orange2","grey")
df1 <- data.frame(Var1,Var2,f)

Var1 <- c(1,3,4,2,5,5)
Var2 <- c(4,2,2,2,5,1)
g <- c("house","car","bridge","stuff","book","other")
df2 <- data.frame(Var1,Var2,g)
```

gives:

```
> df1
  Var1 Var2       f
1    1    4    blue
2    2    3   green
3    6    1     red
4    5    5  orange
5    5    6    grey
> df2
  Var1 Var2      g
1    1    4  house
2    3    2    car
3    4    2 bridge
4    2    2  stuff
5    5    5   book
6    5    1  other
```

and I want new_df to look something like:

```
> new_df
  Var1 Var2       f     g
1    1    4    blue house
2    5    5  orange  book
3    2    3   green   car
```

I can get the new_df by using:

```
df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("Var1", "Var2"))
df4 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("Var1" = "Var2", "Var2" = "Var1"))
new_df <- rbind(df3,df4) %>% unique()
```

but I was wondering if there was a single function that did the same?
Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think you'll find a single function that knows to iterate over all possible combinations of joining variables to get what you want. I think the way you're doing it is likely the simplest (most readable, most declarative). (Other than @jay.sf's neat hack, that is.)

Comment: okok, thanks! i'm not super familiar with sql so will just stick with what i have then:)

Answer (score 1):

You may pout the logic into a small function and use `merge`, but I am not sure if that is what you are after.

```
f <- function(x, c1=1, c2=2, vc=3) {
  o <- data.frame(pmin(x[,c1], x[,c2]), pmax(x[,c1], x[,c2]), x[,vc])
  setNames(o, names(x))
}
merge(f(df1), f(df2))
#   Var1 Var2       f     g
# 1    1    4    blue house
# 2    2    3   green   car
# 3    5    5 orange2  book
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a single SQL statement:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select distinct a.*, b.g 
 from df1 a
 inner join df2 b on min(a.Var1, a.Var2) = min(b.Var1, b.Var2) and
                     max(a.Var1, a.Var2) = max(b.Var1, b.Var2)")
##   Var1 Var2       f     g
## 1    1    4    blue house
## 2    2    3   green   car
## 3    5    5 orange2  book
```

If the idea is to do it in a pipeline refer to the LHS of the pipe as dot:

```
library(magrittr)
library(sqldf)

df1 %>% 
 { sqldf("select distinct a.*, b.g 
     from [.] a
     inner join df2 b on min(a.Var1, a.Var2) = min(b.Var1, b.Var2) and
                         max(a.Var1, a.Var2) = max(b.Var1, b.Var2)") }
##   Var1 Var2       f     g
## 1    1    4    blue house
## 2    2    3   green   car
## 3    5    5 orange2  book
```

Comment: I *really* like how `sqldf` brings the power of SQL queries into R frames! While I don't use the package every day, when I have something squirrely with data (i.e., not simple equality joins, more than `data.table`'s range-joins), it is often the best and fastest method I have to route out what I need quickly. Thanks for the package!